# Numpy's real fft (rfft) - losing power

Tags: fft, python, power-spectral-density, fourier

Related to another problem I'm having, I was looking into the workings of `numpy`'s `rfft2` and `irfft2`. These are special versions of the FFT routine, in so far that it needs less input; because you require the real-space image to be real you only need to 'fill' half of Fourier space - due to symmetry, that's all the information you need.

Now, [in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfftn.html#numpy.fft.irfftn) it is mentioned that performing the inverse transform right after the forward transform should return the original array - *to within numerical precision*. Time to put this to the test.

If I do the following:

```
import numpy as np

fourier_image = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(100,51))
fourier_recovered = np.fft.rfft2(np.fft.irfft2(fourier_image))

print 'Original power: ', sum(sum(abs(fourier_image)**2.))
print 'Recovered power: ', sum(sum(abs(fourier_recovered)**2.))
```

... I find the original power and the recovered power differ at the percent level. That seems a rather big difference to me. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just the best we can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I naively assumed any (N,N/2+1) Fourier image had the right symmetry, but this goes wrong at the 0- and Nyquist frequency because they don't have a symmetric counterpart. Here, you have to impose the symmetry explicitly.

So, if we generate an image:

```
N = 100
fourier_image = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(N,1+N/2))
```

we impose the required symmetry as follows:

```
fourier_image[1:N/2,0] = np.conj(fourier_image[N:N/2:-1,0])
fourier_image[1:N/2,-1] = np.conj(fourier_image[N:N/2:-1,-1])
```

And doing the same as in the question above, we find the input - and recovered power:

```
print 'Original power: ', sum(sum(abs(fourier_image)**2.))
print 'Recovered power: ', sum(sum(abs(fourier_recovered)**2.))
```

which are indeed the same:

```
Original power: 1664.3177945
Recovered power: 1664.3177945
```

For an odd-shaped image this will be slightly different but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question!  Please make this the accepted answer once you are able to.